# Python script with ArcPy cursors won't stop looping?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, cursor

I am running my script in ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop and it doesn't stop processing. The process is overwriting itself because I have to shut down ArcMap manually. How can I stop the overwriting as its not the intended purpose?

```
         with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(mSoils, sField) as cursor2:
             for row2 in cursor2:
                 if row2[0] == '':  
                    row2[0] = row[1]
                    cursor2.updateRow(row2)
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What is `mSoils`? More context, please.

Comment: Are you trying to grab a field from landuse to find the matching soils? I don't see the point of this.. all you're going to end up with is every row in mSoils calculated for each row in mLanduse, overwriting each time, until it will be eventually the value in the last row of mLanduse.

Comment: Rather than create a comment trail that potential answerers may or may not read can you use the **edit** button to revise it with any requested clarifications, please?  [This](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115) should explain why I recommend doing it that way.  How many features are in mSoils?

Comment: You are opening an UpdateCursor and iterating through the entire soils feature class for every row in the SearchCursor. So, yes that will probably take a while.

Comment: I think you should add some pictures to your question that explain, using just a few feature shapes and their corresponding attributes, what you are trying to achieve by your Spatial Join and cursor operations.

Comment: Also, running your code on subsets of your feature classes, with some print statements added within your cursors, is likely to enable you to see what the code is doing and where any issues may need to be addressed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're problem is that you are looping over every single row every single time. You need to specify which row you are wanting to update.

It sounds like you have 2 polygon features and you are wanting to update poly1 from poly2 where poly2 intersects poly1. You can do this without peforming a join.

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(poly2,"*") as c1:
    for row in c1:
        # Select the current poloygon2
        # row[0] is the unique objectid/fid
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(poly2,"NEW_SELECTION","""{} = {}""".format(queryFld, row[0]))      
        # Select all polygon1 that intersect the selected polygon 2
        arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(poly1,"INTERSECT",poly2)
        #Run update cusor on selected
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(poly1, sField) as c2:
            for row2 in c2:
                if row2[1] == '':
                    row2[1] = row[1]
```

Comment: I don't understand this latest edit. . . First of all you aren't even committing your changes. Other than that, this is working code and this is the heart of code, but it would help to have context. What is poly1/poly2/queryFld/sField? Are they strings, lists, objects? And how are they formatted? Also, I think it is a good idea to clear any currently selected items before you call this operation to make sure you aren't limiting your results.